# creating unique user hash for autoincrement field

Tags: php, mysql, auto-increment, uniqueidentifier

So in this app, we have a `user id` which is simple `auto-increment primary key`. Since we do not want to expose this at the client side, we are going to use a `simple hash` (`encryption` is not important, only `obfuscation`).

So when a user is added to the table we do `uniqid(). user_id`. This will guarantee that the `user hash` is `random` enough and always `unique`.

The question I have is, while inserting the record, we do not know the user id at that point (cannot assume `max(user_id) + 1`) since there might be inserts getting committed. So we are doing an insert then getting the last_insert_id`then using that for the`user_id`, which adds an additional db query. So is there a better way to do this?

Comment: why don't you just insert the uniqueid() directly as primary key? then you have just one db query.

Comment: Technically, `uniqid` won't do that. I'd let the database do all the work. Simply create another column called `user_uuid`, make it `unique` and while inserting simply do `user_uuid = UUID()`, `UUID()` being MySQL function. Keep using integer primary keys (they have tons of benefits, do not listen to silly comment above mine).

Comment: N.B The way to go... but why are you exposing the users unique ID to the user in the first place?

Comment: Well it not just for user id, there is also other entities, which we need to pass around through url/hidden fields/cookie/session - so hashing them seems appropriate

Comment: @N.B. that is good option - just that UUID seems just too long...well I guess you cant have everything right? :)

Comment: @UndefinedVariable - well, it's not really *that* long, but think about the benefits - it's definitely always unique (at least during our lifetime), it's incredibly hard to guess what UUIDs you saved so no one can sequentially spider your website by guessing IDs so you can freely expose it to whoever you want.

Comment: @N.B. I guess that is an excellent point, thanks for your input

Comment: Alternatively, you can keep using PHP's `uniqid()`, but bear in mind it's based on microtime() and it's not globally unique. If you want to do `uniqid() . user_id`, then you can use an `AFTER INSERT` trigger that will concatenate supplied `uniqid()` with newly auto_incremented PK.

Comment: that is cool, I never thought about using triggers...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A few things before the actual answer: with latest version of MySQL which uses InnoDB as default storage engine - you **always want an integer pk** (or the famous auto_increment). Reasons are mostly **performance**. For more information, you can research on how InnoDB clusters records using PK and why it's so important. With that out of the way, let's consider our options for creating a unique surrogate key.

### Option 1

You calculate it yourself, using PHP and information you obtained back from MySQL (the `last_insert_id()`), then you update the database back.

**Pros**: easy to understand by even novice programmers, produces short surrogate key.

**Cons**: extremely bad for concurrent access, you'll probably get clashes, and you never want to use PHP to calculate unique indices required by the database.
You don't want that option

### Option 2

Supply the `uniqid()` to your query, create an `AFTER INSERT` trigger that will concatenate `uniqid()` with the auto_increment.

**Pros**: easy to understand, produces short surrogate key.

**Cons**: requires you to create the trigger, implements magic that's not visible from the code directly which will definitely confuse a developer that inherits the project at some point - and from experience I would bet that bad things will happen

### Option 3

Use universally unique identifiers or UUIDs (also known as GUIDs). Simply supply your query with `surrogate_key = UUID()` and MySQL does the rest.

**Pros**: always unique, no magic required, easy to understand.

**Cons**: none, unless the fact that it occupies 36 chars bothers you.

You want the option 3.

Answer (score 1):

> Since we do not want to expose this at the client side

Simply don't.

In a well-designed database, users never need to see a primary-key value. In fact, a user need never know the primary key even exists.

**From your question it seems you actually replace your normal auto-increment ID column with a surrogate id (If not skip to the last paragraph).**

Try creating a column with another unique surrogate ID and use that on your frontend. And you can keep your normal primary ids for relationships etc.'

Remember one of the basic must rules for primary keys:

- The primary key must be compact and contain the fewest possible attributes.

Also integer serials have the advantage of being simple to use and implement. They also, depending on the specific implementation of the serialization method, have the advantage of being quickly derivable, as most databases just store the serial number in a fixed location. Meaning in stead of `max(id)+1` the db has it already stored and makes auto-increment fast.

> So we are doing an insert then getting the last_insert_id then using
>   that for theuser_id`, which adds an additional db query.

`last_insert_id` Isn't actually a query and is a saved variable in your db connection when you performed a insert query.

**If you already have a second column for your surrogate ID ignore all the above:**

> So we are doing an insert then getting the last_insert_id then using
>   that for theuser_id`, which adds an additional db query. So is there a
>   better way to do this?

No, you can only retrieve that uniqid by doing a query.

```
$res = mysql_query('SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()');
$row = mysql_fetch_array($res);
$lastsurrogateid = $row['surrogate_id'];
```

Anything else is making it more complicated than necessary.

Comment: 1. The `unique surrogate ID` is the user hash that I am talking about. 
2. The second query I mentioned in my question is not the `last_inert_id`. `It is the update table with user hash...`

Comment: Just making sure you don't replace the user_id column with the hash unnecessarily. Also it seems unnecessary to make something what let's the end-user see his ID.  Made an edit.